# How to take an image from url and insert into PL SQL table with Python?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to take a picture from URL and insert it on a table. 
My code as follows:

```
    pic = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen( picurl ))
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    pic.save(stream, format="PNG")
    pichex = stream.getvalue()
    cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO GENELOC( GENE_CODE, CYT_LOC , CYT_POS , CHRM_CODE , CHRM_ARM_CODE , BP_START , BP_END , GENE_PICT ) VALUES( :1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 , :7 , utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:8) )",(genecode, cytloc, cytpos, chrmcode, chrmarmcode, bpst, bpend, pichex ))
    con.commit()
```

and when I try this I get this error message:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

GENE_PICT column is a BLOB column.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what about the other columns and their types? What is the structure of your table - what are the values of your variables? You should provide an minimal verifiable  example ..  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Plirkee There is no problem about other columns. I tried inserting "abc" instead of pichex, and it works. The problem is only about GENE_PICT column.

Comment: Have you tried just not using `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW`? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679128/how-to-insert-a-blob-into-oracle-with-python

Comment: I think the error is `CAST_TO_RAW` complaining that its argument is a BLOB, not a VARCHAR2.

Comment: @kfinity Yes it worked finally. Thanks.